# Leaf ordering for hierarchical clustering dendrogram

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

Assuming merging process was completed and we have the history of `n-1` merged clusters (merge two clusters `p` and `q` to cluster `c = min{p,q}`), we are to draw the dendrogram with `k` leaf nodes (or number of records, whichever is smaller). If `k` is smaller then number of records then leaves represent cluster objects

I've seen some papers with optimal leaf ordering algorithms that run in `O(n^4)` time and other fancy algorithms.

I've also heard about "left sliding" ordering.

I'm looking for a simple ordering algorithm to find an admissible ordering of `k` leaf objects for dendrogram, given history of `n-1` merged pairs. Pseudo-code or link would be very nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the SLINK publication (an efficient algorithm for single-link clustering; using $O(n)$ memory and $O(n^2)$ time, as opposed to the $O(n^3)$ standard algorithm), then you will find that it is based on what is called a "pointer representation".
This representation allows rather efficient construction of a non-overlapping dendrogram. Should be in $O(n)$, if you have this representation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've seen this method. The problem is that it applies to only particular inter-cluster metric and operates along with the actual clustering. I need the algo to create dendrogram having the history of mergers after any metric was used.

Comment: You should be able to compute a similar representation from any other dendrogram. As far as I can tell, ELKI is doing that e.g. with UPGMA, too.